# place the mydata_array into the random location of Big_array of zeros

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

mydata is an numpy array of shape(10,100,100) of the form(z,y,x). And i have created the empty array of shape(10,800,800). Now i need to place the mydata_array into some random locations of empty_array such that if I would plot the output, it should look like mydata is placed randomly in the ouput plot of array(10,800,800).

I used the np.hstack() and np.vstack().

But it places the mydata_array side by side. I need to place my_data_array in random location.

How could i do this? Any Suggestions please..

Regards

Raj

Comment: Do you know how to use slice indexing to put one copy of `mydata` some where in `bigarray`?

Comment: No, i don't know to use slice indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demonstration of placing several copies of one array inside another, using slice indexing:

```
In [802]: out = np.zeros((10,10),int)
In [803]: src = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [804]: out
Out[804]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

One copy in the upper left:

```
In [805]: out[:2,:3] = src
In [806]: out
Out[806]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ....
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Several more copies:

```
In [808]: out[4:6, 6:9] = src
In [809]: out[1:3, 4:7] = src
In [810]: out
Out[810]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Just repeat that kind of action for a selection of random locations.  Make sure that the slice ranges match the `src` shape, and that they lie within the dimensions of the target array.

While may be possible to insert many copies at once (the flattening of the answer may be needed), let's start with understanding how to insert one copy at a time.

=========

`@alvis'` answer places the `src` items in shuffled order on one row of the `out` (or wrapped rows):

```
array([[2, 4, 5, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

===================

Looped placement of multiple blocks:

```
def foo1(src, idx, NM):
    out = np.zeros(NM, dtype=src.dtype)
    n,m = src.shape
    for i,j in idx:
        out[i:i+n, j:j+m] = src
    return out

idx=np.array([[0,0],[1,4],[4,4],[8,7],[7,2]])

In [940]: out1 = foo1(src, idx, (10,10))
In [941]: out1
Out[941]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5]])
```

================

Placement of a block with advanced indexing (arrays instead of slices):

```
In [880]: I = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2])
In [881]: J = np.array([3,4,5,3,4,5])
In [882]: out[I,J] = src.flat
In [883]: out
Out[883]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And for multiple blocks

```
def foo2(src, idx, NM):
    out = np.zeros(NM, dtype=src.dtype)
    n,m = src.shape
    ni = len(idx)
    IJ = [np.mgrid[i:i+n, j:j+m] for i,j in idx]
    IJ = np.concatenate(IJ, axis=1).reshape(2,-1)
    out[IJ[0,:], IJ[1,:]] = np.tile(src,(ni,1)).flat
    return out
```

In this small example the alternate is considerably slower (14x).  For (1000,1000) `out` it is still slow (6x).  Most of the time is spent in generating `IJ`.

This handles the `I,J` index calculation much faster (it needs to be generalize), but it is still slower than the looped slicing:

```
def foo3(src, idx, NM):
    out = np.zeros(NM, dtype=src.dtype)
    n,m = src.shape
    ni = len(idx)
    I = np.repeat((idx[:,[0]]+np.arange(2)).flatten(),3)
    J = np.repeat((idx[:,[1]]+np.arange(3)),2,axis=0).flatten()
    out[I, J] = np.tile(src,(ni,1)).flat
    return out
```

This reminds me of work I did years ago to speed up the creation of a finite element stiffness matrix in MATLAB.  There it was per-element stiffness blocks that needed to be placed in a large sparse global stiffness matrix.

==================

Regular pattern with broadcasting (see edit history)

Comment: Yes. I understood this method. Thanks, i was expecting the same kind of output as shown above. But to get same output, do we have any other method like some built-in function in python to placing several copies of one array inside another other than slice indexing.

Comment: I can imagine collecting the required slices into lists, expand those with `np.r_`, and using the index arrays to insert a replicated, flattened `src` into target.  I don't expect any speed gains.

Comment: I added a checker board example.  Not random,but a step in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you don't need to preserve elements relatively to the first dimension of your array. For example, if there is one non-zero element **a** in (100,100) matrix z=0, and two elements **b** and **c** in the matrix z=1, then in your output all **a, b, c** can appear in z=0. In this case I suggest the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

#replace this with your input data
mydata = np.ones((10,100,100))
mydata_large = np.zeros((10,800,800))

mydata_flatten = mydata.flatten() 
ind = np.array([i for i in range(len(mydata_flatten))])
np.random.shuffle(ind)
mydata_large_f = mydata_large.flatten()
np.put(mydata_large_f,ind[:len(mydata_flatten)],mydata_flatten)
mydata_large = np.reshape(mydata_large_f, (10,800,800))
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. But i need to preserve all the elements which are in z-axis too.. For example, placing the cube(z,y,x) randomly in the large cube(z1,y1,x1). such that if you check the output of any slice in z-axis, the image should have all the cubes(i.e,, data of corresponding Slice) is placed non- uniformly. I am trying to place the mydata in large array_data.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt this solution by simple iteration through z axis. Just add mydata[i,:,:] for i in range(10) etc.